# Varieties in the $\mathit{GL}(V)$-module $S_{\lambda}V$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, tensor-products, grassmannians, flag-varieties

It is known that, given a complex vector space $V$ of dimension $\mathit{dim}(V)=n+1$, all irreducible representations for the group $\mathit{GL}(V)$ are parametrized by Young tableaux $\lambda$.
For example for the Young tableaux $\lambda=(d)$ we have that $$S_{\lambda}V=\mathit{Sym}^d(V)$$ and for $\lambda=(1,\dots,1)$ that $$S_{\lambda}V=\bigwedge^k(V)$$
In particular every irreducible $\textit{GL}(V)-$module $S_{\lambda}V$ can be seen as a subvector space of a suitable tensor power $V^{\otimes N_{\lambda}}$.

My question now is the following: is it true that all homogeneous varieties arising as the orbit of a highest weight vector in $S_{\lambda}V$ are only either a Veronese, a Grassmannian or a flag variety?

Answer (score 7):

If $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{n+1})$ is a dominant weight and
$$
\lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_{k_1} > 
\lambda_{k_1 + 1} = \dots = \lambda_{k_1 + k_2} > \dots >
\lambda_{k_1 + \dots + k_r + 1} = \dots = \lambda_{n+1} 
$$
then the orbit of the highest weight vector in the **projective** space $\mathbb{P}(S_\lambda V)$ is isomorphic to the flag variety
$$
Fl(k_1,k_1+k_2,\dots,k_1+\dots+k_r;n+1)
$$
which is embedded by the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(\lambda_{k_1},\lambda_{k_1 + k_2},\dots,\lambda_{k_1+\dots+k_r})$.

Comment: This proves my original thought! Thank you very much.